# Fragment creation and retrieval concurrency

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am currently having an issue with figuring out how to prevent concurrency issues involving fragments.

To store several pieces of data between activity recreations (config changes etc.) I use a retained fragment (without a view).

```
public class ListRetainFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "ListRetainFragment";

    public ListRetainFragment() {}

    public static ListRetainFragment findOrCreateRetainFragment(FragmentManager fm) {
        ListRetainFragment fragment = (ListRetainFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(TAG);
        if (fragment == null) {
            fragment = new ListRetainFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction().add(fragment, TAG).commit();
            Log.e("FRAGMENT_INIT", "New retain fragment created with reference: "+fragment.toString());
        }
        else{
            Log.e("FRAGMENT_INIT", "Existing fragment found with reference: "+fragment.toString());
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    //Storage code omitted.....
}
```

This fragment is then retrieved in the onCreate of the fragments that want to store some data in it.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    listRetainFragment = ListRetainFragment.findOrCreateRetainFragment(getFragmentManager());
}
```

For this example, let's refer to these fragments as `Fragment1` and `Fragment2`, both managed by the same fragment manager and therefore having access to the same `ListRetainFragment` through the `findOrCreateRetainFragment` method.
In most cases this works fine. The fragment is retained and the data properly carries over along with it.

See the logcat when it works as intended:

```
D/FRAGMENT_INIT: New retain fragment created with reference: ListRetainFragment{671e2da ListRetainFragment} //Fragment 1 is the first one trying to retrieve a retain fragment. A new instance is created and added to the fragment manager.
D/FRAGMENT_INIT: Existing fragment found with reference: ListRetainFragment{671e2da ListRetainFragment} //Fragment 2 is the second one trying to retrieve a retain fragment. The originally created fragment is found and returned
//ACTIVITY + FRAGMENT1 + FRAGMENT2 ARE RECREATED (Ex. when changing device orientation)
D/FRAGMENT_INIT: Existing fragment found with reference: ListRetainFragment{671e2da ListRetainFragment} //After recreation Fragment1 finds the orignal fragment and uses it to retrieve/store persistent data
D/FRAGMENT_INIT: Existing fragment found with reference: ListRetainFragment{671e2da ListRetainFragment} //After recreation Fragment2 finds the orignal fragment and uses it to retrieve/store persistent data
```

However, in some device configurations Fragment1 and Fragment2 are part of a 2-fragment ViewPager and therefore created shortly after one another.

This situation leads to the following issue:

```
D/FRAGMENT_INIT: New retain fragment created with reference: ListRetainFragment{214bdd7 ListRetainFragment}
D/FRAGMENT_INIT: New retain fragment created with reference: ListRetainFragment{887e4db ListRetainFragment} 
//ACTIVITY + FRAGMENT1 + FRAGMENT2 ARE RECREATED (Ex. when changing device orientation)
D/FRAGMENT_INIT: Existing fragment found with reference: ListRetainFragment{887e4db ListRetainFragment}
D/FRAGMENT_INIT: Existing fragment found with reference: ListRetainFragment{887e4db ListRetainFragment}
```

Due to Fragment1 and Fragment2 being created so short after one another by the ViewPager, the retain fragment created by Fragment1 (214bdd7) is not properly added to the FragmentManager yet by the time `Fragment2` tries to retrieve it. Therefore a new fragment (887e4db) is created which overrides the one created by Fragment1.

After an Activity recreation the fragment originally retrieved and referenced by Fragment1 (214bdd7) is lost along with its data, due to the recreated Fragment1 now retrieving the retain fragment created by Fragment2 (887e4db).

Is there a way to ensure the previous fragment commit is finished before I try to retrieve it? 
I have already tried the `commitNow()` or `executePendingTransactions()` methods, but they result in a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager is already executing transactions` exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only way to solve your problem is to reconsider how each of your UI fragments obtains a reference to your retained fragment. Rather than having each UI fragment try to retrieve the retained fragment from the `FragmentManager`, I think you should have your **activity** do that and then have your fragments retrieve the retained fragment from your activity.

The root of your problem is that `FragmentTransaction.commit()` is asynchronous. As such, the `FragmentManager` is not a reliable source of answers to the question "has my retained fragment been created yet?" Instead, you should have your `Activity` be the source of truth regarding the retained fragment.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RetainedFragment retainedFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            retainedFragment = (RetainedFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(RetainedFragment.TAG);
        }
        else {
            retainedFragment = new RetainedFragment();

            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .add(retainedFragment, RetainedFragment.TAG)
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    public RetainedFragment getRetainedFragment() {
        return retainedFragment;
    }
}
```

Creating and retrieving your retained fragment by leveraging the `savedInstanceState` parameter guarantees that you will only ever create a single instance of your retained fragment: when the activity starts for the first time it creates a new one and adds it to the `FragmentManager`, and when your activity is recreated after a rotation, it **knows** that the `FragmentManager` will already have an instance of it so it just uses that.

Your UI fragments can now access the retained fragment like this:

```
public class UiFragment extends Fragment {

    private RetainedFragment retainedFragment;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        MainActivity main = (MainActivity) getActivity();
        retainedFragment = main.getRetainedFragment();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I hoped to avoid considering Fragment1 and Fragment2 are used in multiple different activities, which requires maintaining this retain fragment in multiple activities as well. Would delegating this to some kind of base class for the activities lead to any problems?

Comment: @LeonLucardie I can't think of any problems that would cause. If you try it out and it *does* cause problems, we can address them here.